# Performance of simulation model

Tags: matlab, simulation, model, model-evaluation

I have a set of measurement data. The exact inputs of the measurement are used in my simulation model. Does anybody know a reliable measure of performance?
The output signal is not linear, so no Pearson moment correlation can be used. 
The output signal that I want to assess on performance is a vehicle acceleration signal of a acceleration and braking test. The test data looks as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple and useful measure of model performance is the RMSE (root-mean-square error of prediction). It is calculated as the square root of the average of the squared deviations between the model and the data. It's essentially the standard deviation of the errors.

I think it's better than the more-commonly-used Coefficient of Determination (R-squared), which basically normalises RMSE by the standard deviation of the data, because it is independent of the variability of the data, and it is expressed in the same units as the prediction.

Your model and data will have quite a lot of autocorrelation between the errors, but I wouldn't worry about that in the first instance.